# CSS checkbox:checked not changing in safari

Tags: css, safari, checked

Code is working in Firefox and Chrome. I can't get the the CSS to load with Safari. When the checkbox is checked, the div should change its height, making it show up. Is safari not getting the :checked psuedo class or what???
CSS CODE:

```
.the_form_div {background-color:midnightblue;width:400px;padding-left:20px;color:#fff;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;margin:auto;}
#the_box {max-height:0;overflow:hidden;}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #the_box {padding-bottom:200px;}
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vF9Ud/

Comment: it works on Safari 5.1.9/MacOSX 10.6.8

Comment: works on Safari 6.0.4 (8536.29.13)

Comment: Doens't work on Safari 4.1.3/MacOSX 10.4.11 – don't know if it even should?

Comment: I have the same issue did you fix it..

Comment: Yes I did. I didn't have the the most recent version of Safari. I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here - I upgraded to the most recent version of Safari and that fixed my problem. Lesson learned: Always make sure your browser is up to date for CSS!